# SQL Select Where date in (Jan and March) but not in Feb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this in SQL called *Balance*

```
    +----+-----------+-------+------+
    | id | accountId | Date  | Type |
    +----+-----------+-------+------+
    | PK | FK        | Date  | Int  |
    +----+-----------+-------+------+
```

I need to find the *accountId*s that has balance entries in January and March, but **not** in Febuary.
Only in 2018 and Type should be 2.

How would I go about writing my sql select statement?

Thanks

Edit:
What's I've done so far:
Selecting rows that *either* in Jan OR March is not a problem for me.

```
SELECT AccountId, Date FROM Balance
WHERE Month(Date) in (1,3) AND YEAR(Date) = 2018 AND Type =2
ORDER BY AccountId, Date
```

But if an AccountId has a single entry, say in January, then this will be included. And that's not what I want.
Only if an Account has entries in both Jan and March, and not in Feb is it interesting.

I suspect `Group BY` and `HAVING` are keys here, but I'm unsure how to proceed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help to increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask], especially the part about your question should reflect your efforts, and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What are "balance entries"?

Comment: Hint:  Month(Date) In (1,3) and Not In (2) is one way.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @JoeC: right, but say an Account has a single entry in jan and nothing more, then that would be included, right? That's not what I want.
An AccountId is only interesting to me, if it has entries in Jan+march and not feb

Comment: @MJH: no, work :)

Comment: @TabAlleman: BalanceEntries are rows in the table

Comment: Perhaps consider using `HAVING`. Here's a hint to get you started, if you want more, then update your question to be more comprehensive: `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH([Date]) = 1 THEN 1 END) >= 1...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using aggregation:

```
select b.accountid
from balance b
where date >= '2018-01-01' and date < '2019-01-01'
group by b.accountid
having sum(case when month(date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has january
       sum(case when month(date) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has march
       sum(case when month(date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0  -- does not have february
```

Comment: You miss the `Type =2` restriction

Comment: @Gordon WOW, yes!
I think I see it. I would never have been able to come up with this on my own! Thanks
suppose you could use `YEAR(Date) = 2018` for simplicity and add `Type=2`

Comment: If you have an index on the date column, it will be more efficient to compare the column value instead of using  a function on this column wich will not use it. If you want an index on date and want to keep using year(date), you can consider add a computed column : https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/01/sql-servers-year-function-and-index-performance/

Answer (score 0):

You can entirely avoid grouping by using exists:

```
select distinct b.accountid
from balance b
where exists (
        select *
        from balance b1
        where month(b1.date) = 1 and b.accountid = b.accountid
    ) and exists (
        select *
        from balance b1
        where month(b1.date) = 3 and b.accountid = b.accountid
    ) and not exists (
        select *
        from balance b1
        where month(b1.date) = 2 and b.accountid = b.accountid
    )
```